# Why does the borrow checker think that content does not live long enough?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

I am still pretty new to Rust and I have this function:

Edit: Here is a newer version of the function with the same issue as far as I can tell

```rust
pub fn new_from_file_path(path: &str) -> Parser {
    let path_buf: PathBuf = PathBuf::from(path);
    let absolute_path: PathBuf = std::fs::canonicalize(path_buf).unwrap();
    let data: String = std::fs::read_to_string(absolute_path).unwrap();
    let clone = data.clone();

    let s_slice: &str = &clone[..];
    return Parser::new_from_string_data(s_slice);
}
```

Here is the implementation of the new_from_string_data() function

```rust
pub fn new_from_string_data(data: &str) -> Parser {
    let parser = Parser::new(data.chars());
    return parser;
}
```

This is the struct definition for parser :

```rust
pub struct Parser<'a> {
    tokenizer: Tokenizer<'a>,
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error message I am getting

[image: A screenshot of the error message]
Any help would be greatly appreciated, please also let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Could you add the error message you got from trying to build this code?

Comment: Also if I had to guess, I would say it errors since the lifetime of `content` is not `'static` ends before `tokenizer`.

Comment: It's technically not possible to say for sure because the question does not contain a [mre], but I can *virtually guarantee* that `tokenizer` is storing a reference to `content`, and so when `content` is dropped at the end of the function `tokenizer` becomes invalidated. You cannot make something `'static` just by claiming it is `'static`; it has to *actually be* `'static` and `Chars` is not. You could look into [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](/q/43952104/3650362) for another take on the same basic issue.

Comment: @Locke see the revised question

Comment: My guess youre returning a reference to stack data, try passing data to parser making it accept String, so it will take the onwership of the data

Comment: Still not really possible to answer this without seeing the definition of `Tokenizer`. Did you write `Tokenizer` yourself or is it from some crate?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. In the future, try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then edit your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) tips you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: You should also include the error messages as text, since images aren't accessible and won't be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

`new_from_string_data` function returns a `Parser` with the same lifetime as it's input argument `data`.

In the case of `new_from_file_path`,  `data` is `s_slice` which is a slice of the string `clone` owned by the function `new_from_file_path`. Hence the returned `Parser` would reference `clone` which is destroyed when returning from the function `new_from_file_path`

Answer (score 0):

`str::chars()` returns an iterator struct that requires an explicit lifetime as it (presumably, I haven't read the full struct definition myself) references the data passed to `chars()` (`pub struct Chars<'a> { /* fields omitted */ }`), just like your `Parser` struct, and you are generating the referenced variable(s) inside of `new_from_file_path` in the statement `let clone = data.clone();`.

I'd suggest simply adding a lifetime annotation to the function header so it reads as follows:

`pub fn new_from_file_path<'a>(path: &'a str) -> Parser<'a> {...}`

This wont complicate calling the function and tells the compiler that the returned `Parser` struct and its refrences should have the same lifetime as the data passed to the function.